# Redis: Computing Hamming Distance

Tags: redis

Is it possible, using Redis commands, to compute the hamming distance between two entries in {0, 1}^n, s.a.,  https://redis.io/commands/bitfield?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with `BITOP` and `BITCOUNT` commands.

In order to calculate the Hamming Distance, you can *XOR* two given entries, and count the number of `1`s in the result.

```
// The first entry: 10000001
SETBIT k1 0 1
SETBIT k1 7 1
// The second entry: 00000010
SETBIT k2 6 1

// first entry XOR second entry: 10000011
BITOP XOR result k1 k2
// count the number of 1s in the result, i.e. the Hamming Distance between the two entries: 3
BITCOUNT result
```